# Why doesn't using a nullable Guid work in this linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have this code to find the root node of a tree:

```
Guid? currentNode = null; 
var root = db.RecursiveTrees.Where(x => x.ParentId == currentNode).ToList();
```

This query returns 0 results.

If I run this query I get the expected row returned:

```
var root = db.RecursiveTrees.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList();
```

Why doesn't the first query work (using the latest version of entity framework)?

**EDIT:**

Workaround:

```
List<RecursiveTree> root;
if (nodeid == null)
   root = db.RecursiveTrees.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList();
else
   root = db.RecursiveTrees.Where(x => x.ParentId == new Guid(nodeid)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in LINQ to Entities when dealing with nullable value-types. According to the relevant [Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/607404/entity-framework-and-linq-to-sql-incorrectly-handling-nullable-variables), this will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: thanks - I'll change the code to avoid filtering on the nullable Guid

Comment: It's still not fixed in EF 6.1.3. If it ever was fixed, it's broken again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Guid? currentNode = null; 
var root = db.RecursiveTrees.Where(x => x.ParentId == currentNode.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Retrieving the `Value` from a Nullable where `HasValue` is false, will throw an exception.